# Identify Valueand Update Query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have a table with 20 columns, each one a different attribute about a person.

```
        Height      Weight
 Name  Bob    157         165
```

On the other side, I have a progress form which updates three categories for instance.

This form will have:
          Name: Bob
          Attribute Improved: Height           New Height: 165
          Attribute Improved: Weight           New Weight 195

This form fills out a table, each time with only three categories that improved. 
What I'm trying to do is set up a query, which will link the two tables so that access matches the value in the attribute improved field with a column in the attribute table and inputs the new value.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Yes. There is a way, could you please provide the structure of both of your tables you want to link. What is the relationship of the two tables? What columns will be linking these two tables?

Comment: Currently they have no relationship, I'd like to establish a relationship where the progress table appends values to the attributes table by matching the name of the person. The problem is since, I'm only updating three attributes at a time with the form, I need the value of the attribute to match the column title so that it knows where to append the progress info too

Comment: If you would like to do this its very simple. I would suggest you don't match names. In the future people might have the same name. So create a new column that is an identity column for attributes table. So each person has an ID. Once all people have a unique id in the attributes table you then need to create a column in the progress table that matches the id of the correct person from attributes table. This column will be your foreign key. Once you have this relationship the rest is cake.

Comment: Yes but matching the ID's isnt relevant, its about being able to match the value of the improved field with its corresponding column in the attributes table